# Resize font-size on screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, text

how can i resize font-size on screen resolution becouse i want the text to not be more than 1 line when screen resolution its to small. For example: http://prntscr.com/2qa9ze

```
<div class="centerbreaking">
<section id="breaking-news">
    <div id="breaking-news-main" class="shadow">
        <div id="breaking-news-title">Lajmi i fundit</div>
        <div id="<?php if ($mobile) { echo "breaking-news-inside-mobile"; } else { echo "breaking-news-inside"; } ?>">
          <ul id="breaking-news-list">

                 <?php $i=0; foreach ($results as $result) : ?>
    <li><label type="text" name="text<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['text'],ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');?></label></li>
                  <?php $i = $i+1;
                        endforeach;
                   ?>
                   </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#breaking-news-inside').vTicker();
});
</script>
</section>
</div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
#breaking-news-main { float:left; height:40px; margin:5px 0 0; width:100%; background-color:#96040D; color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:bold; }
#breaking-news-title { background: url("images/bn_title.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;color: #000000;float: left;font-size: 12px;height: 40px;line-height: 40px;padding: 0 0 0 10px;text-transform: uppercase;width: 112px;z-index: 999;}
#breaking-news-title p {padding:15px 10px;}
.breaking-news-inside {float: left;height: 40px;line-height: 40px;margin: 0 0 0 5px;padding: 0;width: auto;}
#breaking-news-list {font-size:15px;}
```

Comment: You should use media queries

Comment: And how to use media queries ? :( sry iam new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `font-size` in `em` or `%` (recommended) or if you want in `px` it's also goint to work...
then with `Media Queries` adjust to your needs.

for example:

```
body{font-size:16px}
#bannerDiv{font-size:1em}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){#bannerDiv{font-size:0.8em}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){#bannerDiv{font-size:0.6em}}
```

In this case, `#bannerDiv` will have `1em` that's `16px` declared in `body` tag, when you set the `@media` with `0.6em` that's 0.6 parts of 1... so you are reducing the font from `16px` to `9,6px`

Hope it helps!

*Further reading: [css3-mediaqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)*

**Note**:
this is a `CSS3` feature... if you need to support older browsers, you need to use some `javascript` to do'it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to set your input width in em instead of px. The size of the input will be proportional with the size of your font.
You can also use css property text-overflow:ellipsis (in conjunction with overflow:hidden), to display "..." when your text is too long.

Comment: +1 for the `ellipsis` trick!... just want to add that probably and in most cases you will need to add `white-space:nowrap` to avoid break line. (note that `text-overflow:ellipsis` is also a CSS3 feature)